# Can I trigger the Hololens Calibration sequence from inside my application?

Tags: mrtk

I have a hololens app I am creating that requires the best accuracy possible for hologram placement. This application will be used by numerous individuals. Whenever I try to show the application progress, I have to have the user go through the calibration process, otherwise the holograms appear to have way too much drift.

I would like to be able to call the hololens calibration process automatically when the application opens. Later, after I set up user authentication and id management, I will call the calibration process when a new user is found.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/calibration

I have looked into the calibration (via the above documentation and elsewhere) and it seems that all it is setting is IPD. However the alternative solutions I have found that allow for dynamic ipd adjustment appear to be invalid for UWP Store apps. This makes them unusable for me.

I am looking for any help or direction, or if this is even possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to to this, you need to use the LaunchUriAsync protocol to launch the following URI: **ms-hololenssetup://EyeTracking**

Here is an example implementation, obtained from the [LaunchUri example in MRTK](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Examples/Demos/HandTracking/Script/LaunchUri.cs)

```
public void LaunchEyeTracking()
{
#if WINDOWS_UWP
    UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(async () =>
    {
        bool result = await global::Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("ms-hololenssetup://EyeTracking"));
        if (!result)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Launching URI failed to launch.");
        }
    }, false);
#else
    Debug.LogError("Launching eye tracking not supported Windows UWP");
#endif
}
```

Comment: hello julia schwarz. Thank you so much for that answer! Do you also know a way to await until the calibration is completed, in order to resume the current app? ^^
I googled but can't find an answer, help very appreciated! = )

Answer (score 1):

For HL2, can the opposite be achieved? i.e. block the prompt for eye calibration from ever happening while running an app?

Since they use AEP now, the checkbox to turn this off is gone.